# partition table on a disk partition; how to access?

Tags: loop-device, partition-table

I've made a TrueOS VM in VirtualBox, using a vmdk that virtualises a physical harddisk partition (sda5) as a complete disk. As a result, I now have a GPT/GUID partition table on that sda5 partition (sda has a GPT/GUID partition table itself).

I can see that partition table when I create a loopback device (`losetup /dev/sda5 /dev/loop0`) on the host but I haven't yet figured out how to create the /dev/loop0p1, /dev/loop0p2 etc. devices in order to mount the partitions on /dev/loop0.

Is this possible? Could it be related to the max_part parameter of the loop device module? FWIW, the loop module is built into my kernel, and /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part returns 0 ... can I change that value without rebooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

should create the partition devices for you.

Note: the partition devices will be /dev/mapper/loop0p1 etc.

Comment: Forgot to mention... I recalled kpartx from the past, but when I didn't find it on my current system I assumed it had gone irrelevant for 4.x kernels. Wrongly so, it indeed does the trick. Thanks!